# How can I get a banner-like footer?

Tags: html, css

My footer has a background, however I can't get it to have a solid black rectangle. The black will only surround my text, not my wrapper div nor my footer.

```css
.footer {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}

.DIV37n5 {
  float: left;
  width: 37.5%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="DIV12n5">
      <table width="20%" border="1" class="InfoTbl">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Public Sources of Info</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://wikileaks.org/">WikiLeaks</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://kongregate.com/">And if ya get 
                bored</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="DIV50">
      <p class="PromiseTxt" align="right">This organization is a nonprofit organization dedicated to the spread of knowledge. Remember to always double-check your sources because even we
        <strong>aren't</strong> perfect!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="DIV37n5">
      <p class="PromiseTxt" align="center"> Updated about 1 minute ago
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Those .DIV classes are all the same, with float:left and width depending on the numbers stated.

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle

Comment: Because you have a float , clear it

Comment: This code does what you ask. The problem and the other side

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mikekaylor98/cxeqakLk/ Is that what I do?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani There's no need for a fiddle when you can insert a snippet in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a float , clear it

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/1nw0m7tw/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="DIV12n5">
      <table width="20%" border="1" class="InfoTbl">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Public Sources of Info</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://wikileaks.org/">WikiLeaks</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://kongregate.com/">And if ya get 
            bored</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="DIV50">
      <p class="PromiseTxt" align="right">This organization is a nonprofit organization dedicated to the spread of knowledge. Remember to always double-check your sources because even we
        <strong>aren't</strong> perfect!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="DIV37n5">
      <p class="PromiseTxt" align="center"> Updated about 1 minute ago
      </p>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't exactly sure that float was doing this.